# How do I pass a filename parameter to MediaPlayer in android kotlin?

Tags: android, function, kotlin, audio

How do I pass a filename parameter to MediaPlayer in android kotlin?

I have a sound file called "hello.wav" which is in the res/raw directory.  I have tried the following code and it will not accept the parameter sndfil as there is no file called sndfil.wav in the res/raw directory...

```
    private var sndfil = "xxxxxxxxxx"

    fun playnow (sndfil: String) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sndfil)
        mp.start()
        return
    }

    playnow("hello")
```

How can a filename be passed as a parameter to android MediaPlayer ?

Comment: Thank you so much!  Brilliant!  It works fine now.

Comment: Could you select my answer as accept?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the `getIdentifier` method it returns a resource identifier for the given resource name.

```
fun playnow (sndfil: String) {
    val resourceIdentifier = resources.getIdentifier(sndfil, "raw", packageName)
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,resourceIdentifier)
    mp.start()
    return
}

playnow("hello")
```